# How can products with images be displayed first in category or filter for an entire collection? (list.phtml)

Tags: product-collection, list-view

Magento store owners with thousands of products will no doubt have difficulty getting images and descriptions for every single product. To try and overcome this myself, I found some code that would allow products that contained images to be displayed first.

```
$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->setOrder('image'/*or small_image*/, 'desc')
```

The problem is, it only moves product images first per page and not the entire product collection.

Example: Total of 50 products, 30 contain images and descriptions, the remaining 20 do not.

The desired result would be: if the page sorting was done by 10 products per page, the first 3 pages would contain all the products with images and descriptions followed by the remaining 2 pages of products that do not.

**How can products with images be displayed first in a category or filter for an entire collection?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced with this some time ago. Here is what I came up with.
I've created a module in which I've overwritten the `addAttributeToSort()` method in the product collection.
Let's call the module `Easylife_Sorting`.

**`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Sorting.xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_collection>Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php`** - overwritten collection - follow the comments in the code

```
<?php
class Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection {
    public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC){
        //don't screw up the admin sorting
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID){
            return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        }
        //use sorting by image or not only in the default sorting.
        //if the customer sorts by name, let them sort by name.
        //showing products with images first will confuse them if they sorted by name or price or something else other than position
        if ($attribute == 'position') {
            $useAttribute = 'small_image'; //image attribute to use: can also be 'image' or 'thumbnail'
            $this->addAttributeToSelect($useAttribute);
            //add a 1|0 flag for products depending on:
            // - the image attribute value is empty
            // - the image attribute value is null
            // - the image attribute value is set to 'no_selection'
            $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
                'has_image',
                "(CASE WHEN {{image}} = '' OR {{image}} IS NULL OR {{image}} = 'no_selection' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)",
                array('image'=>$useAttribute)
            );
            //sort by the flag set above and then by position
            $this->getSelect()->order(array('has_image DESC', 'position '.$dir));
            return $this;
        }
        //if not sorting by position let magento do its magic
        else {
            return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this can be improved by adding a config setting to enable or disable this functionality but this should be easy.

Comment: This is just a response to Marius. I was not sure exactly how to respond, I am not able to add a comment to Marius's response.
<br/><br/>
Would I need to create a new folder named Easylife?
Or would I use something else? I am currently using all default settings. The version I am using is Community Edition 1.9.1.1
<br/><br/>
Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but I seem to get the `There has been an error processing your request` page with a huge stack trace that I'm not able to make much sense of.

Comment: you can check the var/report folder for a file with the same name as the error id you receive in the browser and get more info about what went wrong. I cannot answer if I don't know the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question here with an output of the log file @Marius - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/sorting-product-list-by-multiple-attributes